# Do I need nvidia driver on my new dell 5720 with Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: nvidia, 13.04, dell, nvidia-optimus, inspiron

Just got new Dell Inspiron 5720. As I know there are two video cards - Intel and Nvidia.

And as I see in system information, I use Intel Ivy Bridge. But how about Nvidia?

I know about Bumblebee and also know about new Nvidia 319 driver which must support Optimus.

Can anybody suggest which driver to use?

Answer (score 1):

The nvidia-current package from the default Ubuntu repositories is the safest and most stable graphics driver to install, and it is also supported by Ubuntu software updates. The current version of nvidia-current for Ubuntu 13.04 is 304.88, and it works with Optimus. In 18.04 and later the nvidia-current package is no longer in the default Ubuntu repositories. Instead the following command will install the recommended proprietary Nvidia graphics driver and its dependencies automatically.

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install && sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Bumblebee for your Optimus. New Nvidia drivers (319) has a initial support of Optimus, but not GPU switching yet.

This guide will help you a lot: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/bumblebee-321-released-with-ubuntu-1304.html

There's also info's on Ubuntu's site: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee